# R: read numeric values wrapped in quotes from csv

Tags: r, csv, quotes, read.table

This is probably an easy one but I seem unable to figure it out.

I have a csv-file with all entries wrapped in quotes, also numeric values, like this one, say `xy.csv`:

```
"y","z"
"1.1","bla"
"2.1","blubb"
```

So far, I have been reading and re-declaring these files using

```
dat <- read.table("yz.csv",colClasses=rep("character",2), header=TRUE)
dat$y <- as.numeric(dat$y)
```

Now as the number of numeric columns increases, as in `qz.csv`

```
"q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"
"1.1","1.2","1.3","1.4","1.5","1.6","1.7","1.8","1.9","bla"
"2.1","2.2","2.3","2.4","2.5","2.6","2.7","2.8","2.9","blubb"
```

I felt it is time to do this more professionally to prevent the following from happening

```
dat <- read.table("qz.csv",colClasses=rep("character",10), header=TRUE)
dat$q <- as.numeric(dat$a)
dat$r <- as.numeric(dat$b)
...
dat$y <- as.numeric(dat$y)
```

Is there a way to get the read.table function to ignore the quotes around the numbers, so I can use

```
dat <- read.table("qz.csv",colClasses=c(rep("numeric",9),"character"), header=TRUE)
```

which currently gives me the error that `scan() expected 'a real', got '"1.2"'`?

Edit: Here is the original [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e39d9ofpeienn59/testfile.csv?dl=0) and here is the code I use for the original that is giving me the error:

```
doc <- read.csv("testfile.csv", collClasses=c("character","character",rep("NULL",50),rep("numeric",7),"NULL","NULL"),  col.names=c("country","code",rep("bla",50),"doc08","doc09","doc10","doc11","doc12","doc13","doc14","bla","bla"), skip=4, check.names=F, header=T)
```

Comment: Added an example, I hope this helps. If not, I can give some of the original file.

Comment: Can you add a `header=T` in the read function? It seems that this is the problem as your first line includes characters

Comment: Of course, obviously it has been there in my original code. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

updated to show minimal example... I can't figure it out. I've tried the `readr` package also...

```
a <- textConnection('"A", "B", "C"
                    "a", "1", "1"
                    "b", "2", "2"')
df <- read.csv(a, colClasses=c("character", "NULL", "numeric"), 
               col.names=c("AA", "BB", "CC"))
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '"1"'

library("readr")
> df <- read_csv(a, col_types=c("c", "-", "n"), 
+                col_names=c("AA", "BB", "CC"))
Error in names(spec$cols) <- col_names : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]
In addition: Warning message:
Insufficient `col_types`. Guessing 2 columns.
```

Comment: Strangely, it works with your code using `textConnection` but not when that text is in a .csv file.

Comment: I've updated my code to read from a file. Seems to still work. Can you provide your file to test?

Comment: I have added it to the post. Note that I exclude a couple of columns when reading the file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That dropbox file seemed to work fine also... see update above

Comment: I see, thanks. However, as soon as I add the colClasses argument to exclude some columns from being imported, the problem returns.

Comment: Okay, I see the problem. I've updated my post to show a minimal example of it. I can't figure it out though...

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying and improving this post, cory!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best bet is to use NA in colClasses for the numeric columns:

```
dat <- read.table("qz.csv",colClasses=c(rep(NA,9),"character"), header=TRUE)
```

Then type.convert() will recognize the numeric data and convert it.  Alternatively, to reduce the clutter of converting columns after reading it, you can do something like

```
dat <- read.table("qz.csv",colClasses=rep("character",10), header=TRUE)
dat[,1:9] <- lapply(dat[,1:9], as.numeric)`
```